# How does OS kernel get known connected hardware configuration to save it in `/proc` files?

Tags: linux-kernel, hardware, proc

In my student assignment I'm asked to track how Linux kernel discovers configurations of any device connected. For instance, the system has a new printer plugged in. As far as I can see, all features of this utility (i.e. vendor name, model, device number etc.) will be evaluated in kernel mode before adding fresh hardware info to `device` file held by  `/proc` directory. I can grasp how it goes running once kernel detects a new device available. Otherwise it still escapes me how the kernel detects some device as plugged one to start collecting and saving its configuration stuff charging `proc` for that. It there any pretty in-depth explanation of this point to make clear operations between device plugging and passing data into file system? And how much does device driver enable this data to be extracted?

Comment: The best resource is the source code.

Comment: @Pedro- the Linux source code is about 12 million lines. Where would you recommend starting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Once a device is detected, udev comes into play: https://linux.die.net/man/8/udev
- This post describes how devices are detected when the computer is powered on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854931/how-does-the-os-detect-hardware
- For USB, the USB subsystem detects when a device is attached. see here: http://www.linux-usb.org/USB-guide/x75.html

Comment: Very helpful response, thanks.